# appendChild con clases en vez de con un tag name

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tengo que asignarle un `.innerHTML`, dentro de un `<section>` con las clases `class="row separar container-fluid"`, pero no logro hacerlo.
Mi código es este:

```
class Producto {
   constructor(id, descripcion) {
            this.id = id;
            this.descripcion = descripcion;
        }
    }
    let productos = [];
    
    productos.push(new Producto("751100", "Manija"));
    productos.push(new Producto("851100", "Manija"));
    productos.push(new Producto("751200", "Manija"));
    productos.push(new Producto("753100", "Manija"));
    
    for (const producto of productos) {
        let article = document.createElement("article");
        article.className = "articulo col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 carta"
        article.innerHTML = `<div>
                                <img src="../imagenes/ft-nosotros.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Imagen de Producto">
                                <h3 class="codigo">${producto.id}</h3>
                                <p class="descripcion">${producto.descripcion}</p>
        
                                <div>
                                    <a href="" class="btnCompra">Agregar al Carrito</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>`
        document.body.appendChild(article);
        console.log(article);
        
        
    
    
    }
```

En caso de hacer esto: `document.body.appendChild(article);`, me pone el footer por encima de los productos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `document.body.appendChild(article);` estás agregando los artículos al cuerpo del documento y no a la sección que deseas. Antes del ciclo crea una variable con la sección y la usas para agregar los artículos.

Lo ideal sería que asignes ID, pero, si debes obtenerlo por clase, entonces inicia con punto y remplaza los otros espacios por puntos:

```
// Obtener sección
let section = document.querySelector('.row.separar.container-fluid');

for (const producto of productos) {
    let article = document.createElement("article");
    article.className = "articulo col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 carta"
    article.innerHTML = `<div>
                            <img src="../imagenes/ft-nosotros.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Imagen de Producto">
                            <h3 class="codigo">${producto.id}</h3>
                            <p class="descripcion">${producto.descripcion}</p>
    
                            <div>
                                <a href="" class="btnCompra">Agregar al Carrito</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
    // Agregar a sección y no al documento
    section.appendChild(article);
}
```